# Jquery- how to identify a clicked button's class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Right now, I have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".follow-button").click(function(){
        alert("asdf");
    }
});      

<button class="follow-button" align="right" align="center">
        Follow 
 </button>
```

But when I click the button, nothing happens.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you'd check your debug console you'd see you'd missed a bracket.

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* You're not running the code with the developer console open.

Comment: ok wow. Yea I didn't see that... I never knew about the whole Javascript console and stuff. New to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a closing parenthesis and semi-colon following the `click`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".follow-button").click(function(){
        alert("asdf");
    });
});
     ^----- there
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".follow-button").click(function(){
        alert("asdf");
    });  // <----here 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to add ); to the end of the function

```
$(".follow-button").click(function(){
        alert("asdf");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The other submitters answered your question but I figured I would comment. JavaScript has very unintended consequences that happen when syntax is wrong and it can be hard to figure out what is actually going wrong. I would recommend using JSLint (or JSHint) to catch these sorts of silly errors. (http://www.jshint.com)

Comment: And yes, as commented, always have your debug console open while developing in JavaScript!